# compilation error on clock_gettime and CLOCK_MONOTONIC

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, libc

I'm using clock_gettime in a program. I've tried including  as well as  but neither works. I have also added -lrt to my compiler arguments but still I get the same errors.

This is on

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)
GNU ld version 2.23.52.0.1-55.el7 20130226
ldd (GNU libc) 2.17
```

Compiler output:

```
gcc -o main packet.c connect.c transport.c accept.c main.c close.c util.c receive.c send.c congestion.c -Wall -g -std=c99 -lrt
util.c: In function ‘millis’:
util.c:42:21: error: storage size of ‘t’ isn’t known
     struct timespec t;
                     ^
util.c:43:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘clock_gettime’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t);
     ^
util.c:43:19: error: ‘CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, &t);
               ^
```

Makefile

```
CFLAGS = -Wall -g -std=c99
LIBS = -lrt

# Should be equivalent to your list of C files, if you don't build selectively
SRC=$(wildcard *.c)

main: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

Top of util.h

```
#ifndef UTILS_438_H_
#define UTILS_438_H_

#include "const.h"
#include "data.h"
#include "transport.h"

#include <time.h>
```

Top of util.c

```
#include "util.h"

#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Please let me know if I can supply more information to help answer this

Comment: that's not a linker error,, `#include` problem somewhere

Comment: you should figure out why you're getting the compiler warnings and errors. It's _not_ a link problem. Since you're including `time.h` you shouldn't have any warnings. Can you create a [mcve] so we can help you further? Maybe the `c99` flag gets in the way? (just trying to guess something)

Comment: will you try -std=gnu99 instead?

Comment: Also, linking order can and does matter. Surely someone here can explain in more detail, but I'd be wary of putting `-lrt` at the very end of my `gcc` command. I suspect you may run into "undefined reference" problems with that at the end after you resolve this issue.

Comment: Replacing -std=c99 with -std=gnu99 allowed it to compile. Removing the -std also compiled fine. What is wrong with using c99?

Comment: @Steven When you use -std=c99, you only get access to the standard C functions in the standard header files. clock_gettime() from time.h is defined by the posix standard, not the C standard.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before including the header(`<time.h>`), do

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L
```

---

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html

> Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
>
> ```
>    clock_getres(), clock_gettime(), clock_settime():
>           _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
> ```

---

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html

> _POSIX_C_SOURCE
>         Defining this macro causes header files to expose definitions as
>         follows:
>
> ```
>   ·  The value 1 exposes definitions conforming to POSIX.1-1990 and
>      ISO C (1990).
>
>   ·  The value 2 or greater additionally exposes definitions for
>      POSIX.2-1992.
>
>   ·  The value 199309L or greater additionally exposes definitions
>      for POSIX.1b (real-time extensions).
>
>   ·  The value 199506L or greater additionally exposes definitions
>      for POSIX.1c (threads).
>
>   ·  (Since glibc 2.3.3) The value 200112L or greater additionally
>      exposes definitions corresponding to the POSIX.1-2001 base
>      specification (excluding the XSI extension).  This value also
>      causes C95 (since glibc 2.12) and C99 (since glibc 2.10)
>      features to be exposed (in other words, the equivalent of
>      defining _ISOC99_SOURCE).
>
>   ·  (Since glibc 2.10) The value 200809L or greater additionally
>      exposes definitions corresponding to the POSIX.1-2008 base
>      specification (excluding the XSI extension).
> ```

Comment: tried that on MinGW, still the same compilation errors... You read this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47571

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Mingw does not give you access to all posix functions. The OP is using Linux, so this will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Simply replace -std=c99 with -std=gnu99.
Thisway you do not have to add _POSIX_C_SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the following linker and Compiler flags

```
CFLAGS  = -g -Wall -std=c99 -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_GNU_SOURCE
LDFLAGS = -lpthread -lrt
```

you can get the build done in the Linux systems. -lrt linker and -D_POSIX_SOURCE are the important ones

Comment: This answer is not helping at all. Please, provide further links to your statements and give appropriate solution. The way you responded does not solve what OP asked.